# How to add css-keyframes to vaadin components?

Tags: java, css, vaadin, css-animations

I'd like to add a keyframe-animation to a `vaadin` `Label` component: the background should make a colored transition from `red` to `yellow`.

But the bg color does not change in any way. Am I missing anything?

```
private Label label = new Label("background red fading");
lable.setCss("red");
```

css:

```
.v-label-red {
    @include red;
}
```

keyframe:

```
@-webkit-keyframes red {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: yellow;}
}
@keyframes red {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: yellow;}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

be sure to have the @keyframes out of your main `@mixin` of the theme.  Next
your `.v-label-red` needs the background set (most likely to the same as the
`to` in the keyframes and also it needs some time to handle it (now it
basically goes from white -> red -> yellow -> white in no time.  here is an
example, that should bring you on the right track:

CSS

```
@import "../reindeer/reindeer.scss";

@keyframes keyframe1 {
    from {background: red;}
    to {background: yellow;}
}
@keyframes keyframe2 {
  from {background: yellow;}
  to {background: red;}
}

@mixin app {
  @include reindeer;

  .keyframe1 {
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-animation: keyframe1 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: keyframe1 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: keyframe1 1s linear;
    animation: keyframe1 1s linear;
  }

  .keyframe2 {
    background: red;
    -webkit-animation: keyframe2 1s linear;
    -moz-animation: keyframe2 1s linear;
    -ms-animation: keyframe2 1s linear;
    animation: keyframe2 1s linear;
  }

}
```

Vaadin UI code (groovy)

```
@VaadinUI
@Theme('app')
@CompileStatic
class AppUI extends UI {

    final static String K1 = 'keyframe1'
    final static String K2 = 'keyframe2'

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final layout = new VerticalLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(true)
        layout.setMargin(true)
        final headline = new Label('Hello World')
        headline.addStyleName(K1)
        final button = new Button("toggle", {
            if (headline.styleName.contains(K1)) {
                headline.addStyleName(K2)
                headline.removeStyleName(K1)
            } else {
                headline.addStyleName(K1)
                headline.removeStyleName(K2)
            }
        } as Button.ClickListener)
        layout.addComponents(headline, button)
        setContent(layout)
    }

}
```

This code will fade the label on loading and will fade between the two states
on button clicks.

Comment: Your first statement, `"be sure to have the @keyframes out of your main @mixin of the theme"`, was of great help.